# PyPy vs. CPython 3.8 - Difference in "number of iterations" with the same code?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, sudoku, pypy

I've stumbled upon an interesting phenomenon while I was tinkering with my sudoku solving algorithm written in Python.

I'm counting iterations in the backtracking algorithm and saving the number in a log file. (The algorithm seems to be completely deterministic, hence I'm intrigued by the sudden increase in the number of iterations to get the same output.)

Now the interesting part is:

**When I tried to run the same code with PyPy (3.7-v7.3.3-win32) instead of Python 3.8 (64bit) the number of iterations about doubled when running with PyPy to 629505 from the 362073 with running with CPython.**

My question is: Does anyone know why is this difference in the number of iterations?

Log:

```
Iterations: 629505, Time Taken: 0.8950409889221191, File: ./sudokus/9x9.csv  -- PyPy 3.7
Iterations: 629505, Time Taken: 0.895305871963501, File: ./sudokus/9x9.csv  -- PyPy 3.7
Iterations: 362073, Time Taken: 2.1060104370117188, File: ./sudokus/9x9.csv -- Python 3.8
Iterations: 362073, Time Taken: 2.1779544353485107, File: ./sudokus/9x9.csv -- Python 3.8
```

For another sudoku file the difference is alo there but negligible:

```
Iterations: 19443164, Time Taken: 106.15500068664551, File: test_0.csv -- Python 3.8
Iterations: 19443259, Time Taken: 13.188998937606812, File: ./sudokus/test_0.csv  -- PyPy 3.7
Iterations: 19443259, Time Taken: 13.118957042694092, File: ./sudokus/test_0.csv  -- PyPy 3.7
```

My code is this:
https://github.com/kasztp/kiwi.com-sudoku-solver/blob/OCR/sudoku_solver.py

Comment: The code would need to be posted here directly, and ideally reduced down to a [mcve] that shows a narrow example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Code goes in the question, not in an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stepped through your code in two concurrent debugging sessions, one for each interpreter. The `set`s in `self.mask` do not look the same between the two interpreters - they contain the same values, but in a different order. Even on the second recursion of `solve` (when `self.iterations` becomes `2`), the flow of execution diverges because of this difference. I don't know if that's the exact cause of the discrepancy you're seeing, but I'm guessing it has to do with `set`s having guaranteed insertion order in one implementation, and not in another.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In that case, if the order is quasi-random in one interpreter, then shouldn't I see some variation in the number of iteration at each run? (Here both the interpreters are consistent with the number of iterations, only they have different numbers between each other.)

Comment: @kasztp When an implementation says that it doesn't guarantee insertion-order for sets, that's all it means. It doesn't mean that the items in the set will be ordered randomly. They will be ordered in some arbitrary, but deterministic way. Not necessarily in insertion-order, or in a way that's specified by the standard. An implementation is free to establish the order of a set however it likes.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're enumerating over sets at line 117.  This order is unspecified, i.e. arbitrary, in CPython.  In PyPy you get the order in which you've put the items in the set.